# Specify random particle start colour with no animated change?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skemitternode

Is there a way to have particles spawn with a random per particle colour based on the current "Color Ramp"? The particles do not change colour over their lifespan, they are simply assigned a colour from somewhere along the "Color Ramp" at birth and keep that colour until they die.

The result of this would be a mix of particles at birth with blend colours from RED through to BLUE.

[image: Color Blend]

In my tests I only seem to be able to get the behaviour where particles spawn as RED and then gradually turn to BLUE as the approach the bottom of the screen.

[image]
[image: Falling Leaves]

Comment: You don't wish for them to animate to the bottom of the screen but stay in place and change colors?

Comment: @JohnRiselvato - With the colour ramp the particles animate from red (top) to blue (bottom). What I was after is not having the particles animate in color at all, but rather spawn with a constant color (from the ramp) and then keep that color for their entire lifespan. Like autumn leaves falling from a tree, some are green, some are yellow, some are orange, they just start with their individual color and fall (they don't change color as they fall)

Comment: I used snow as the original, then changed the sprite to the leaf (ill, add the *.png above)

Comment: I think the problem is that the colour ramp only works over time, all the particles always start red (and then you have the option to blend from red to blue) I don't think this gives you the ability to assign a fixed blend colour (based on the ramp) on a per particle basis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, It looks like you can't use a predefined `sks` file for the `SKEmitterNode`... I was able to figure this out by programmatically creating the `SKEmitterNode`. The reason why is because it doesn't look like when you initiate an `SKEmitterNode` with an `sks`, it doesn't respond to `setParticleColor:` but programmatically initiating one does.

Now today, this past hour, was the first time I ever messed with an SKEmitterNode, so you'll have to bear with me because I couldn't figure out how to get the snow effect perfect, but I'm sure you can just mess with the values an `SKEmitterNode` allows you to change.

In any case, I'm going to assume that the `SKEmitterNode` is presented on the SKScene (that's the only way I know how to get your desired effect).

First you'll need to make you're `SKEmitterNode` a global/property/etc because you'll need access to it later.

---

In the `MyScene.m`:

```
@implementation MyScene {
    SKEmitterNode* leafEmitter;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
        leafEmitter = [[SKEmitterNode alloc] init];
        [leafEmitter setParticleTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"saFMB.png"]];
        [leafEmitter setParticleBirthRate:10];
        [leafEmitter setScale:0.5];
        [leafEmitter setYAcceleration:-10.0];
        [leafEmitter setParticleSpeedRange:100];
        [leafEmitter setParticleLifetimeRange:100.0];
        [leafEmitter setParticlePositionRange:CGVectorMake(self.size.width, self.size.height)];
        [leafEmitter setPosition:CGPointMake(100, 400)];
        [leafEmitter setParticleBlendMode:SKBlendModeAlpha];
        [self addChild:leafEmitter];
}
```

So what i've done here is programatically created the particle effect, this is where you'll change the animation/speed/etc variables to get the best particle effect you are looking for.
I would suggest [reading this](http://wwwbruegge.in.tum.de/lehrstuhl_1/home/98-teaching/tutorials/507-sgd-ws13-tutorial-particle-systems) for more details.

---

Now remember how I said that it needs to be presented on the SKScene? Well that's because we are going to be taking advantage of the `update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime` function that comes along with an `SKScene`.

Inside the `update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime` is the location where we will be changing the `SKEmitterNode`'s color. Since this update function is called every frame it makes it easy to change the color without any fancy timers or such. Not sure if this is a good idea, but it's the idea that counts.

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
[leafEmitter setParticleColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:drand48() saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0]];
[leafEmitter setParticleColorBlendFactor:1.0];
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
```

In this case, we are changing the color to a random RGB value but i'll let you select the colors yourself.

---

In return this is what my code has produced:

[image]

---

All this said, it doesn't look like you can get the effect you want solely using the particle interface unfortunately.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your time and effort in putting that answer together. I see what your doing and it looks good to me, I will give it a try in the morning. Much appreciated, perfect answer.

Comment: If you set the 'particleColorSequence' variable of the SKEmitterNode to nil then the SKParticleColor is not ignored anymore. Creating an SKS typically sets it to non-nil causing other color attributes to be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

What I've found works, without needing to add code to an update() function is to apply the following changes to the emitter.

@john-riselvato is correct (even now, after 7 years) use the editor to define this, but you can get the desired effect with the following code:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class RandomColorEmitterNode : SKEmitterNode {

    override init() {
        super.init()
    
        self.particleColorSequence = nil
        self.particleColorBlendFactorSequence = nil
        self.particleColorBlueRange = 255
        self.particleColorGreenRange = 255
        self.particleColorRedRange = 255
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    
        self.particleColorSequence = nil
        self.particleColorBlendFactorSequence = nil
        self.particleColorBlueRange = 255
        self.particleColorGreenRange = 255
        self.particleColorRedRange = 255
    }
}
```

This way, with a simple call to:

```
if let emitter = RandomColorEmitterNode(fileNamed: "flower.sks") {
    self.addChild(emitter)
}
```

the emitter is initially loaded from the SKS file you create in the editor, and then the color attributes are overriden by the class.