# Trying to change the color of the particles emitted by my SKEmitterNode from WITHIN the code

Tags: sprite-kit, skemitternode

I have an app where the user can edit an emitter node and take a screenshot to the photo library. In the settings where they can change stuff like the birthrate, angle, ect. I allow them to change the color of the emitter node.

I am using:

```
node.particleColor = [SKColor redColor];
```

and it isn't changing the color of the particles.

However when I added `NSLog` statements to it and asked it what `node.particleColor` was it returned `1 0 0 1`, which is what I was expecting but the node never changes color.

Any ideas as to what I can do to change its color?

Comment: Please can someone explain to me what this has to do with the `xcode IDE`??????

Comment: The answer for this can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19818606/2043580

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specify random particle start colour with no animated change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813252/specify-random-particle-start-colour-with-no-animated-change)

Answer (score 11):

Hey i think i just figured out this problem. Not sure if your code is different however.

For me i have a SKEmitterNode created like this

```
SKEmitterNode *explosion = [NSKeyedUnarchiver
                                        unarchiveObjectWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"Explosion" ofType:@"sks"]];
```

then to change its color i do this

```
explosion.particleColor = [SKColor redColor];
```

then in i set the blend factor to 1

```
explosion.particleColorBlendFactor = 1.0;
```

and finally i turn the color sequence to nil (this was the tricky part)

```
explosion.particleColorSequence = nil;
```

By turning the color sequence to nil, it no longer ignores the particle color. Not sure why it initially wasn't set to nil like the reference says, but this is what fixed it for me. Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you mind posting your code and I will try and work through it?

Comment: Problem was in my code. I did not set particleColorSequence to nil.

Comment: Really helpful for `particleColorSequence = nil` which wasting much time to find it.

Comment: Also, make sure the particle texture color is white; eg. if it's black it will not blend with the `particleColor`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `colorBlendFactor` as well to blend the set color with the particle texture:

```
node.colorBlendFactor = 1.0;
```